# How to remove FullCalendar-4 events in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, fullcalendar-4

I am attempting to build an interactive calendar using `FullCalendarV4` and `Vue.js`. So far, I have set up the code to enable event inputs using a prompt method in a `handleDateClick` function. I want to append a functional delete button to each event. The documentation says that this can be done using `eventRender` callback. I tried using this callback to append a button but to no avail. Any recommendations on how to make this work? My code is below. Thanks!

```
<template>
  <div class='demo-app'>
    <FullCalendar
      class='demo-app-calendar'
      ref="fullCalendar"
      defaultView="dayGridMonth"
      :header="{
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
       }"
      :plugins="calendarPlugins"
      :weekends="calendarWeekends"
      :events="calendarEvents"
      @dateClick="handleDateClick"
      />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import FullCalendar from '@fullcalendar/vue'
import dayGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/daygrid'
import timeGridPlugin from '@fullcalendar/timegrid'
import interactionPlugin from '@fullcalendar/interaction'

export default {
  components: {
    FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [ // plugins must be defined in the JS
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin // needed for dateClick
      ],
      calendarWeekends: true,
      calendarEvents: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    handleDateClick(arg) {
    var newTitle = prompt(arg.dateStr);
      if (newTitle != null) {
        this.calendarEvents.push({
          title: newTitle,
          start: arg.date,
          allDay: arg.allDay
        })
      }
    },
    eventRender: function(event){
      var btn = document.createElement("button");
      btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
      event.appendChild(btn);
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang='scss'>

// you must include each plugins' css
// paths prefixed with ~ signify node_modules
@import '~@fullcalendar/core/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/daygrid/main.css';
@import '~@fullcalendar/timegrid/main.css';

.demo-app {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.demo-app-top {
  margin: 0 0 3em;
}

.demo-app-calendar {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 900px;
}

</style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind `@eventRender` method to `FullCalendar` component
To access element in `eventRender`, you need to use `event.el`. You can check [the document here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender)

```
   <FullCalendar
          class='demo-app-calendar'
          ref="fullCalendar"
          defaultView="dayGridMonth"
          :header="{
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
          }"
          :plugins="calendarPlugins"
          :weekends="calendarWeekends"
          :events="calendarEvents"
          @dateClick="handleDateClick"
          @eventRender="eventRender"
    />

    methods: {
        eventRender(info) {
          var btn = document.createElement("button");
          btn.appendChild(document.createTextNode("x"));
          info.el.appendChild(btn);
        }
    }
```